# Error Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running apache kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

i was following this step to download apache kafka into my device windows https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

but when i did this `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

i always stuck with this error `Error Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g.`

where my wrong at?

Comment: Follow this to fix the error : https://i-am-jabi.medium.com/fixing-classpath-is-empty-69288c1509a2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you might have downloaded the Kafka sources (labeled src) rather than the binaries

Download the **binary** link for the desired Kafka version from here: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: so what should i do sir? i dont understand

Comment: Download the correct binary package instead (the one without src in the name)

Answer (score 0):

check the space between directories where you have downloaded your kafka. Remove space and run again

Answer (score 0):

For wilndows commands we need put `.` represents current directory

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```